# Захват кадра с web-камеры (зелёный прямоугольник вместо картинки)

Tags: delphi, web-камера

Была разработана программа (на Delphi XE), делает снимки с камеры в bmp-формате и всё это идёт в акт на печать. Всё работает отлично.
ПО Тестировалась: на Win7 64bit ПК, на WinXP 32bit ПК, на WinXP 32bit ноутбук.
Но вот стоило запустить на объекте у заказчика (далеко не современные ПК, платформы ещё на DDR1, OS WinXP). Как произошёл нёх!
Все они начали делать не снимки, а зелёные прямоугольники.
Что это, из-за чего такое происходит? И как это исправить (обойти)?
——————
Снимок делается следующим образом:

```
begin
  //открываем камеру
  hWndC := capCreateCaptureWindowA('My Own Capture Window',
  WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE,
  Image1.Left,
  Image1.Top,
  Image1.Width,
  Image1.Height,
  Form1.Handle,
  //Image1.Canvas.Handle, //тут белое
  //Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, // тут пусто
  0);
  if hWndC <> 0 then
    begin
     SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, 0, 0); // подключаемся к драйверу
     SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_SAVEDIB, 0, longint(PAnsiChar(AnsiString('data\photo.bmp')))); // делаем снимок
     SendMessage(hWndC, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0); //отключаемся от драйвера
     hWndC := 0;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: У камеры много настроек, штук надцать. Настройками яркость/контраст/другие можно добится: черный квадрат, белый квадрат, зеленый квадрат ну и других приколов

Comment: Возможно, криво стал драйвер камеры или не хватает каких-нибудь кодеков.

Comment: @I_CaR, Каким образом делается снимок камеры?.. Не с экрана-ли монитора? Если да, то убедитесь что там вывод изображения идёт не на оверлей, т.к. в этом случае там действительно только зелёный квадрат, а видеоизображение накладывается видеокартой уже после. Тогда надо поковыряться в настройках приложения для просмотра изображений с камеры.

Comment: А ещё подобное бывает, если пытаться выставить камере параметры, которые она не поддерживает. К примеру, выставляем размер 1280х800, а она только 1024х768 умеет.

Comment: @Alekcvp дописал в вопросе способ снимка

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, вот что-то всё больше и больше склоняюсь к этому же ответу.

Comment: @I_CaR, а изображение с камеры у них в программе видно? Просто есть подозрение, что у них в системе не один драйвер захвата, поэтому ваша камера имеет индекс драйвера отличный от 0 и, соответственно, вы захватываете не её.